# Find values in array and change them efficiently

Tags: python, arrays

I am working with a large array with around 300 000 values. It has 100 000 rows and 3 columns. I am doing iterations with this array and if any value in the first column exceeds a limit of lets say 10, I want the number to be replaced. Is there any more efficient way than running something like this?:

```
for i in range(N):
    if array[i][0]>10:
        array[i][0] = 0
```

I need to repeat this sequense for the other two columns as well which included with all my other iterations makes my code pretty slow.

Comment: Use NumPy, if you can. Especially if your array is entirely numerical.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your array to a numpy array (`numpy.asarray`) then to replace the values you would use the following:

```
import numpy as np
N = np.asarray(N)

N[N > 10] = 0
```

[numpy.asarray documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've assumed you may not want to use the same threshold/replacement value for each column. That being the case, you can pack the three items in a list of tuples and iterate through that.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.ndarray(your_array)
#Edited with your values, and a more than symbol
threshold = 10
column_id = 0
replace_value = 0
arr[arr[:, column_id] > threshold, column_id] = replace_value
```

Set `threshold`, `column_id` and `replace_value` as you require.

Comment: Ill check this out! In my example i guess it should be `arr[arr[:, column_id] > threshold, column_id] = replace_value`

Comment: In your example, `threshold = 10`, `column_id = 0`, and `replace_value = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you`re looking for something like that:

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> a = array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> a[a>5]=10       # <--- here the "magic" happens
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5, 10],
       [10, 10, 10]])
```

Comment: If _I_ understand the question, they'd want `a[a>10] = 0`.

Comment: @martineau The numerical values are not important, the concept is.

Comment: IMO the concept would likely be easier to grasp if your code solved exactly the problem stated (and coded) in the OP's question.

Comment: Yeah thats seems like a good trick! Is it possible to do that only with the first element of each row? (Using your array, checking if 1,4 and 10 is exceeding this limit)

Comment: @martineau if the OP provided a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I goes with him, since he doesn't, I goes with my simple example.